# VBA clear cell range based on a certain condition

Tags: vba, cell

This problem may seems pretty simple but I have been dealing with it for 2 days now and cant get it done. I searched other forums to see if they have this same problem but didnt find close to tyhis one. 
So I have range K:T starting from row 2 and need to clear the cells that contains #N/A. I wrote the code below but cant seem to make it work.

```
Sub Clear_cells()
    Dim rng As Range, i As Integer

    'Set the range to evaluate to rng.
    Set rng = Range("K:T")

    'Loop backwards through the rows
    'in the range that you want to evaluate.
    For i = rng.Rows.count To 1 Step -1

        'If cell i in the range contains an "N/A", delete cell content
        If rng.Cells(i).Value = "#N/A" Then rng.Cells(i).CellRange.ClearContents (1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cells contain an error value (i.e. `#N/A`) rather than the string `"#N/A"` then you need to check for an error value instead of checking for a string.

Replace

```
For i = rng.Rows.count To 1 Step -1

    'If cell i in the range contains an "N/A", delete cell content
    If rng.Cells(i).Value = "#N/A" Then rng.Cells(i).CellRange.ClearContents (1)
Next
```

with

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel in rng
    If IsError(cel.Value) Then
        If cel.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then cel.ClearContents
    End If
Next
```

or, if you want to check for all error conditions (such as `#DIV/0!`), just use

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel in rng
    If IsError(cel.Value) Then cel.ClearContents
Next
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. So i replaced the code using the first option you sent, but i am getting a Runtime error 13: Type mismatch on this part: If cel.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then cel.ClearContents

Comment: @jackie - Fixed - I shouldn't have tested against `CVErr(xlErrNA)` until I confirmed that the cell contained an error.

Answer (score 0):

use the function isna to check for #N/A

```
 If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNa(rng.Cells(i)) Then rng.Cells(i).CellRange.ClearContents (1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! Apparently, the when I replaced the code with IsNA statement, I am getting an overflow runtime error "6" on this part of the code:  For i = rng.Rows.count To 1 Step -1

Comment: @jackie - You will need to declare `i` as `Long` - `Rows.Count` will be `1048576`, which is bigger than an `Integer` can handle.  (You should also note that your loop is only processing the first 10% of the cells in the range, and that `CellRange` is not an actual method [or, at least, I have never seen it], and that `ClearContents` doesn't accept a parameter.)